# Show that $3\mid xy$ in $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Part 1:

If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers for which $gcd(x, y, z) = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, show that $3\mid xy$

Part 2:

Now again if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive integers for which $gcd(x,y,z) = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, can a similar result to the one in (part 1) be said modulo 5? Not that $5|xy$, but one of $x,y,z$?

Comment: Hint: $a^2\equiv 0\text{ or }1\pmod 3$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Primitive Pythagorean triplets can be characterized precisely.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwxrhy0rsk38vx0/Pythagorean_triplets.pdf?dl=0)

> If $x^2+y^2=z^2$, where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\gcd(x,y,z) =1$, then $x=m^2-n^2$, $y=2mn$ and $z=m^2+n^2$, where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ and are of opposite parity.

[From the above, we can immediately conclude that $3$ divides $xy$. Similarly, we can conclude that $4$ divides $xy$ and $5$ divides $xyz$. Look here for more properties on Pythagorean triplets.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbvdth7r2xnybm0/Properties.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: You really linked to dropbox, a site that is specifically meant to be temporary storage? The point of this site is to be a permanent repository for answers, not just to answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $3$ is a prime, so $3 \mid xy \iff 3\mid x$ or $3\mid y$. Suppose to the contrary that $3 \nmid x$, and $3\nmid y$, then:$x = 1,2$ mod $3$ and $y = 1,2$ mod $3$. Then:

$x^2+y^2 = 2$ mod $3$, and $z^2 = 0,1$ mod $3$. Contradiction, proving the claim.

Comment: If I add a second part to this problem, would you help with that by adding to this answer?

Comment: @Sandikae All you questions have been answered in my answer and in the links provided.